# Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, edição, syntax-highlighting

Existe alguma razão para o syntax highlight (realce de sintaxe) não funcionar aqui no SOpt?

É possível ativar esse recurso?

## Atenção! Com a adoção do CommonMark a forma apresentada aqui não funciona mais.

Agora use assim e mum linha antes do código, encerra com a mesma marcação sem precisar do nome da linguagem:

````
``` python
````

Se existir uma *tag* da linguagem não precisa disso.

Comment: @Sklivvz This *not* status-complete, highlighting doesn't work automatically based on language tag like on SO.

Comment: Pt: estou avisando um moderador/dev que isto não está resolvido, o highlight deveria ser mais esperto e aplicado automaticamente conforme as tags da pergunta - como no SO.

Comment: @Gabe Isso já é `status-pronto`, não?

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu tinha aberto a edição um tempo atrás, e esqueci de mudar. Valeu pelo lembrete

Comment: @Gabe: Ainda não funciona para Objective-C. Aliás, nem com `language: objective-c` funciona, ao contrário do Stack Overflow em inglês.

Comment: @Bavarious Acredito ter consertado. Verifiquei com 3 perguntas diferentes. Se você vir algum que não está colorindo, me avise (com link)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ainda não parece estar a funcionar ou a funcionar a 100% o destaque do código mediante a linguagem indicadas nas tags.

Com a indicação da linguagem a carregar a partir do comentário, reparei hoje que está a funcionar bem *(para as que já utilizei)*.

O código é destacado através do [google-code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), onde a indicação da tag da linguagem ou o comentário com a linguagem são utilizados para adicionar uma class de CSS que vai destacar o código com cores.

Deixo aqui a lista das várias opções disponíveis, para quem tiver interesse em formatar as perguntas e respostas através do comentário enquanto o "sistema" está a ser concluído.

## Opções disponíveis:

```
┌────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┐
│  Texto puro        │  <!-- language: none -->         │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  YAML              │  <!-- language: lang-yaml -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  XQuery            │  <!-- language: lang-xq -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Wiki pages        │  <!-- language: lang-wiki -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  VHDL '93          │  <!-- language: lang-vhdl -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Visual Basic      │  <!-- language: lang-vb -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  tex               │  <!-- language: lang-tex -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  TCL               │  <!-- language: lang-tcl -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  SQL               │  <!-- language: lang-sql -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Scala             │  <!-- language: lang-scala -->   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  R docs            │  <!-- language: lang-rd -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  S, S-plus, e R    │  <!-- language: lang-r -->       │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Protocol Buffers  │  <!-- language: lang-proto -->   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Perl              │  <!-- language: lang-perl -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  PHP               │  <!-- language: lang-php -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  (Turbo) Pascal    │  <!-- language: lang-pascal -->  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Nemerle           │  <!-- language: lang-n -->       │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  MUMPS             │  <!-- language: lang-mumps -->   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  OCaml, SML, F#    │  <!-- language: lang-ml -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  MATLAB            │  <!-- language: lang-matlab -->  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Lua               │  <!-- language: lang-lua -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  LLVM              │  <!-- language: lang-llvm -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Lisp, Scheme, CL  │  <!-- language: lang-lisp -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Java              │  <!-- language: lang-java -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  HTML              │  <!-- language: lang-html -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Haskell           │  <!-- language: lang-hs -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Go                │  <!-- language: lang-go -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Erlang            │  <!-- language: lang-erlang -->  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Dart              │  <!-- language: lang-dart -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  CSS               │  <!-- language: lang-css -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Clojure           │  <!-- language: lang-clj -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Basic             │  <!-- language: lang-basic -->   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  AGC/AEA Assembly  │  <!-- language: lang-apollo -->  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  C                 │  <!-- language: lang-c -->       │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  C++               │  <!-- language: lang-cpp -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  C#                │  <!-- language: lang-cs -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Bash, Shell e Csh │  <!-- language: lang-bash -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  JSON              │  <!-- language: lang-json -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Python            │  <!-- language: lang-py -->      │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Ruby              │  <!-- language: lang-ruby -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Rust              │  <!-- language: lang-rust -->    │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Regex             │  <!-- language: lang-regex -->   │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  XML               │  <!-- language: lang-xml -->     │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  Coffee            │  <!-- language: lang-coffee -->  │
├────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┤
│  QML               │  <!-- language: lang-qml -->     │
└────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┘
```

<sup>**Nota:** Alguma em falta ou algum erro, é só indicar ou corrigir!</sup>

## Como usar:

Antes do bloco de código, aplicar o comentário com a indicação da linguagem em questão seguido de uma linha em branco.

- Formatar um bloco de código:

  ```
  <!-- language: lang-sql -->

  SELECT * FROM algures WHERE local='mar'
  ```
- Múltiplos blocos de código de uma só vez:

  ```
  <!-- language-all: lang-sql -->

  SELECT * FROM algures WHERE local='mar'
  ```

Comment: No FAQ original acredito que tem todas opções http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/147423

Comment: De onde vem esta lista? Acho que tem linguagens aí que o sistema não trata, ou pelo menos não estão na lista oficial linkada no comentário acima. @Guilherme QML funciona?

Comment: @bfavaretto Tanto essa lista quanto a que o BrunoLM linkou parecem incompletas. QML por exemplo funciona (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/430/429) e não vi em nenhuma lista.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Estão sempre a surgir actualizações para a _Syntax Highlight_ via comentário. Como já fizeste e muito bem, sempre que vires algo novo, adiciona à lista. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto A lista é proveniente de alguns _posts_ no METÃO e de algumas horas a testar. Também tem por base o suporte original da ferramenta que torna tudo isto possível :)

Comment: Tem suporte para Markdown e n funciona o famoso ```[lang], acho que seria mais simples terem adicionado o highlight do markdown. Até o discord que é feito pra gamers tem isso implementado e o SOF que tem 100 mil anos na web e é justamente voltado para códigos não tem.

Answer (score 3):

Eu recebi uma sugestão de edição [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/qual-a-diferenca-entre-break-pass-e-continue-em-python) que apenas fazia o highlight. Parece ser possível, talvez não da forma (simples?) como se faz no SOEN (não sei como se faz isso por lá).

A forma que o usuário encontrou para fazer o highlight de python foi anteceder os blocos de código com:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
```

Comment: Não tinha percebido a tag de 'status-pronto' antes de postar a minha resposta... =(

Comment: Está tudo no meio do caminho. Algumas linguagens está conseguindo fazer automático, outras precisam declarar, e outra não funcionam mesmo.

Comment: Isso é realmente muito importante. Seria muito bom se seguisse o mesmo modelo do GitHub, por exemplo: ```php. No entanto, tendo a opção, pra mim, não importa muito a sintaxe a ser utilizada.