# O Syntax Highlight ainda não funciona para várias linguagens

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, edição

A questão [Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/podemos-ter-sintax-highlight-nos-codigos-como-no-so) foi marcada como resolvida pela equipe, porém pode ser observado que algumas linguagens ainda não estão realçando a sintaxe. Em um teste que fiz, mesmo colocando a tag da linguagem na pergunta, não realça. Só realça se forçarmos a linguagem via *hint* (como em `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`).

Além disso, está um pouco feio, pelo menos não segue o padrão de cores ou mesmo fonte que o realce do SO onde é mais legível.

Edição:
Pelos testes que fiz o realce está funcionando desde que indique a linguagem com a marcação apropriada mas não de forma automática como ocorre no original.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O mapeamento das tags para as linguagens correspondentes precisa ser feito manualmente para cada tag por um moderador (os usuários com ♦ no nome). Eles têm um drop-down para isso na página de informações da tag (`br.stackoverflow.com/tags/{tag}/info`). Por favor criem uma nova pergunta com a tag [suporte](/questions/tagged/suporte) para cada mapeamento de tag-linguagem, para que um moderador cuide disso.

---

The mapping from tag to code language has to be done manually for each tag by a moderator (a user with the . There is a drop-down for that in the tag info page (`br.stackoverflow.com/tags/{tag}/info`). Please create a new question with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag for a specific tag-to-syntax mapping, so a moderator can take care of it.