# Syntax Highlighting para Lua

Tags: suporte, status-pronto

A tag Lua não está fazendo coloração de sintaxe automáticamente. É preciso adicionar um `<!-- language: lang-lua -->`na mão.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info

Aparentemente isso precisa ser corrigido por algum moderador: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/557/1745

Answer (score 5):

Feito. Há alguns meses eu associei várias tags às respectivas linguagens, quando era possível (ou seja, quando a linguagem está na lista de opções a que tenho acesso). Mas eu tinha deixado passar [lua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua), perdão.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta :)