# Syntax highlight para Python-3.x

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tags, edição, syntax-highlighting

Vi que a pergunta [Porquê esta função mostra a lista antes de retornar mas retorna None](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39845/201) não renderiza o código com *syntax highlight* para [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x).

Conforme [O Syntax Highlight ainda não funciona para várias linguagens](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66/201) é só abrir um pedido de suporte aqui no meta.

Comment: Pronto! Feito! *Done!* (Já deu o mínimo de caracteres)