# Syntax highlighting para Haskell

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, syntax-highlighting

O syntax highlighter do sopt não está detectando a linguagem Haskell (lang-hs) automaticamente. [Algum moderador pode acertar isso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/o-syntax-highlight-ainda-n%C3%A3o-funciona-para-v%C3%A1rias-linguagens/557#557), por favor?

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ativado o highlighting para Haskell (`lang-hs`).

Comment: Ué, não tem a opção `lang-hs` pra Haskell?

Comment: ops. tinha sim. eu estava procurando "lang-haskell" e passei reto no "hs".

Comment: Mas parece que o resultado ficou pior?!

Comment: Talvez o exemplo que você olhou estava cheio de erros de sintaxe. O lang-hs sempre funcionou pra mim lá no SO em inglês.