# Tags sem Syntax Highlight: golang, node.js, react e react-native

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, syntax-highlighting

<sup>Estou abrindo essa pergunta conforme dito [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66/100416), mas não sei se podia abrir uma única para mapear "várias" tags.</sup>

Percebi que essas tags estão sem *syntax highlight*, segue a lista `tag -> lang-`:

- [golang](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) -> `go`
- [node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) -> `javascript`
- [react](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react) -> `javascript`
- [react-native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native) -> `javascript`