# Syntax Highlighting incorreto na linguagem Ruby

Tags: suporte, syntax-highlighting

Vejam o print em Ruby:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há pelo menos 4 bugs no syntax highlighting:

- Tudo que vem depois do `#` em uma linha (comentário) deveria ser da mesma cor. Como o `#` fica em azul, provavelmente o correto seria o comentário todo ser azul.
- Os symbols, palavras que começam com `:` (dois pontos), deveriam ter uma cor diferenciada, normalmente vermelho.
- Certas palavras reservadas como `def` e `end` deveriam ter cor diferenciada também. Provavelmente amarelo, como já funciona para `if`, `else` e `class`.
- Os nomes dos métodos (oque vem depois do `def`) deveriam ser em azul, como já acontece com os nomes das classes.

Comment: Se não mudou e não estou enganado isto é fornecido por um serviço da Google, portanto a SE não tem muito o que fazer.  O *bug* não é dela. Me corrijam se eu estiver errado.

Comment: @bigown Dei uma olhada aqui no StackOverflow-EN e a formatação é ligeiramente diferente da versão em português. ([Veja por exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859062/rails-seed-circular-dependecy-error), note como o `end` é em azul). Porém isso deve ser porque aqui nós provavelmente temos uma versão anterior do software do site. (Digo isso porque há outras pequenas diferenças de layout no site em comparação com o nosso, etc.)

Comment: Pode ser que as cores do CSS no nosso site não tenham sido bem escolhidas então.

Comment: Em que pergunta você tirou esses prints? Por exemplo [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3958/como-atualizar-com-ajax-uma-lista-apos-a-acao-de-um-formulario-remoto) `def` e `end` ficam em vermelho. Testei também os comentários, e fica tudo em cinza depois do `#`. Só os symbols e os nomes dos métodos é que não são marcados mesmo (nem no SO são, mas lá usam cores diferentes, azul em vez do vermelho).

Comment: @bfavaretto Tirei o print daqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14708/como-fazer-autenticacao-com-devise-via-ajax/14737#14737

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na [postagem em questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14708/como-fazer-autenticacao-com-devise-via-ajax/14737#14737) o problema não está no highlighter. Ele está certo, o erro é a linguagem. Por padrão o sistema tenta determinar a linguagem da pergunta pelas tags. Naquela pergunta há duas relevantes: [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) e [ruby-on-rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). Provavelmente a eurística usada foi que existem mais questões sobre [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) que [ruby-on-rails](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails). Sendo assim foi determinado que a linguagem é javascript, não ruby, e a coloração foi feita de acordo.

Editei sua resposta adicionando um comentário hint dizendo que todos os blocos de código da postagem são ruby:

```
<!-- language-all: lang-ruby -->
```

Mais detalhes: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/150/429

Comment: Legal. Ainda assim isso poderia ser melhorado em relação aos `:symbols` e nomes dos métodos, mas isso seria ser perfeccionista demais. =)

Comment: @Andrey Ai já é uma questão com a biblioteca [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). Uma alteração feita lá eventualmente, talvez, em algum futuro remoto, chegará e fará diferença aqui.

Comment: Na verdade não tem a tag ruby lá, tem ruby-on-rails. Não sei se essa está associada à sintaxe de Ruby, o Gabe pode dizer.

Comment: @bfavaretto Opa, bati o olho rápido, não reparei. Se me lembro bem, está associada ao ruby sim.