# Realce de sintaxe para tag htaccess e apache (etc) consideram "slashs" (//) como comentários

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, markdown

Em arquivos `.htaccess` e `httpd.conf` (e afins) usa-se o `#` (hash) para comentar algo, assim:

```apacheconf
# meu htaccess
RewriteRule . /oi.html [QSA]
```

No entanto o realce de sintaxe está considerando `//` como comentários também:

```apacheconf
RewriteRule . http://test/oi.html [QSA]
```

Pode-se efetuar o teste aplicando o `<!-- language: lang-apacheconf -->`:

```
<!-- language: lang-apacheconf -->

    RewriteRule . http://test/oi.html [QSA]
```

Comment: Relacionado [Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/33/3635)

Answer (score 2):

Para usar apache e afins o recomendável foi `lang-bsh`: [What is the better highlighting language for http Apache conf](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136395/what-is-the-better-highlighting-language-for-http-apache-conf)

Assim:

```
<!-- language: lang-bsh -->

    # comentário
    RewriteRule . http://test/oi.html [QSA]
```

Resultado:

```bsh
# comentário
RewriteRule . http://test/oi.html [QSA]
```

As tags que creio que poderiam receber este realce de sintaxe seriam o [htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess) e [apache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache), scripts bash variantes que procurei na comunidade (não é meu "forte") aparentemente já usam o `lang-bsh` ou tem a tag [bash](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)

Comment: Pode fazer uma lista das tags que devem ter o reallce de bash aplicado?

Comment: Posso sim, assim que possivel, creio que vai além do apache, então pode demorar um pouco, mas assim que possivel eu edito e lhe notifico. Muito obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Sem problema! Não precisa ser absolutamente correto, mas um top 3-5 já era bom pra resolver o problema nas tags principais

Comment: @Gabe só encontrei duas tags "top" na nossa comunidade [tag:apache], [tag:htaccess] que ainda não tem realce. Se encontrar mais "compatíveis" eu notifico.

Comment: Mudei as duas pra `lang-bsh`. Deve ser aplicada automaticamente nos posts agora

Comment: Obrigado @Gabe, isto é ótimo! Uma duvida, isto ocorrerá no SOen/SOja/SOru/SOes? Ou é algo apenas aqui?

Comment: Só aqui. A colorização das tags é de acordo com cada site. Mas eu posso mudar nos outros... Boa ideia.

Comment: @Gabe Eu costumo postar tudo aqui no meta.pt, pq lembro-me que vc ou outra pessoa me disse que vc geralmente levava isto para ser cuidado e não necessitava postar no Metão.

Comment: Bom, a separação de escopo entre MSO/MSE/MSint pra um usuário internacional é assunto pra um meta post por si só. Não é bem fácil de separar as coisas. Mas no caso das cores aqui, no final das contas é algo particular de cada comunidade, mesmo que elas provavelmente acabem chegando na mesma decisão. Eu to mexendo nas tags lá pra tentar adiantar o processo, não porque seja um problema em todas elas.

Comment: Entendi, blz. Obrigado isso ajudará muito.

Answer (score 0):

A questão é que este realce de sintaxe não existe, pelo menos não achei nenhuma evidência de que ele exista.

Então está sendo usado o realce de sintaxe padrão, onde `#`, `//` e `/* */` são considerados comentários.

Abaixo eu usei `<!-- language: lang-jbueno -->`

```jbueno
# Comentário

// Comentário

/* Comentário */

if(codigo) { int b = 1; }
```

Comment: Tem razão qualquer lang-xxxxx invalido gera isto. Não me recordo de onde tirei `lang-apacheconf`, talvez eu tenha lido algo errado nos comentários do SE. Mas lembro que copiei de algum lugar assim.