# Por que a sintaxe de código da minha resposta não ficou destacada?

Tags: suporte, syntax-highlighting

Nessa resposta

[Controle de usuário em visual studio c# a propriedade fica desabilitada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/374441/controle-de-usu%C3%A1rio-em-visual-studio-c-a-propriedade-fica-desabilitada/375609#375609) eu não sei o que fiz de errado.

Coloquei um código em C#, ele aparece formatado porém não aparece o realce de cores.

O código fica todo acinzentado.

Primeiro tentei com o `{ }` da barra de edição, e não funcionou o destaque. Posteriormente marquei com ```` ```C# ````. Em ambos os casos o texto permaneceu acinzentado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pergunta não tinha a tag C# (eu acrescentei em seguida), por isso o sistema não estava usando um *syntax highlighter* (destaque de sintaxe) específico .

Quando for assim, ou se coloca a tag na pergunta, ou se adiciona um comentário HTML de linguagem ou uma tag antes do trecho de código.

Exemplo de uso com comentário HTML

> ```
> Você pode ver neste trecho uma diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP
>
> <!-- language: lang-php -->
>
>     echo "123\n456";
>     echo '123\n456';
> ```

Exemplo de uso em markdown (sem o prefixo `lang-`)

> ````
> Você pode ver neste trecho uma diferença entre aspas simples e duplas em PHP
>
> ```php
> echo "123\n456";
> echo '123\n456';
> ```
> ````

Isto forçará o trecho de código a usar o destaque de PHP.

Se em vez de `language` usar `language-all`, o destaque será aplicado a todos os trechos subsequentes (ou até que nova instrução de sintaxe seja encontrada).

- `<!-- language: lang-c -->`: somente o trecho seguinte
- `<!-- language-all: lang-c -->`: todos os trechos deste ponto em diante

Uma pequena relação das linguagens suportadas atualmente:

```
Detecção padrão         default
Texto puro              lang-none
```

Nativas do *highlighter*:

```
Bash/Shell              lang-bash
                        lang-bsh
                        lang-csh
                        lang-sh
C, C++, Objective-C     lang-c
                        lang-cc
                        lang-cpp
                        lang-cxx
                        lang-cyc
                        lang-m
C#                      lang-cs
CoffeeScript            lang-coffee
HTML, XML, XSL          lang-html
                        lang-xml
                        lang-xsl
Java                    lang-java
JavaScript              lang-js
                        lang-javascript
JSON                    lang-json
Perl                    lang-pl
                        lang-perl
Python                  lang-py
                        lang-python
                        lang-cv
Regex                   lang-regex
Ruby                    lang-rb
                        lang-ruby
```

Providas por extensões:

```
Clojure                 lang-clj
CSS                     lang-css
Dart                    lang-dart
Erlang                  lang-erl
                        lang-erlang
Go                      lang-go
Haskell                 lang-hs
LaTeX, TeX              lang-latex
                        lang-tex
Lisp, Scheme            lang-cl
                        lang-el
                        lang-lisp
                        lang-lsp
                        lang-scm
                        lang-ss
                        lang-rkt
Lua                     lang-lua
MATLAB                  lang-matlab
OCaml, SML, F#          lang-fs
                        lang-ml
Pascal, Delphi          lang-pascal
Protocol Buffers        lang-proto
R, S                    lang-r
                        lang-s
Rust                    lang-rc
                        lang-rs
                        lang-rust
Scala                   lang-scala
SQL                     lang-sql
Swift                   lang-swift
VHDL                    lang-vhdl
                        lang-vhd
Visual Basic, VBScript  lang-vb
                        lang-vbs
```

Relacionado:

> [Podemos ter Syntax Highlight nos códigos como no SO?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/33/70)
>
> [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108)