# Como inserir texto sem destaque sintático usando o triplo tique (```)?

Tags: suporte, syntax-highlighting

Recentemente percebi que foi adicionada a opção de adicionar códigos usando o triplo tique (```). Fiquei muito empolgado com isso, pois acho mais natural e coincide com meu uso do markdown no GitLab.

Com compensação, fiz uma pergunta sobre Dart e, ao usar o triplo tique sem especificar a linguagem, foi feito destaque sintático para Dart (como se fosse um bloco criado com o espaçamento inicial).

Meus testes e resultados obtidos:

````
```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```
````

[image: sem demarcação de linguagem]

`raw`:

````
```raw
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```
````

[image: linguagem "raw"]

`plain`:

````
```plain
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```
````

[image: linguagem "plain"]

`txt`:

````
```txt
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```
````

[image: linguagem "txt"]

---

No final das contas, acabei caindo no jeito antigo, com o `<!-- language: lang-none -->` e o espaçamento no começo da linha:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->

    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
    \_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
                   |                     |          |     |        |
                   |                     v          |     v        v
                   |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
                   v                           Repositório
         Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```

Virou:

[image: sem destaque sintático]

É possível obter esse resultado sem destaque sintático usando o bloco com triplo tique?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pelo que testei, você pode colocar `none` como linguagem:

````
```none
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
\_______________________________/ \_____/  \______/ \____/ \______/ 
               |                     |          |     |        |
               |                     v          |     v        v
               |            Usuário do GitHub   v   Branch    Path
               v                           Repositório
     Domínio de arquivos estáticos
```
````

Ficando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ='D Me chame de bobo, essa opção óbvia nem me veio à cabeça

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Bobo.

Comment: Caso algum leitor não tenha pego a "lógica" de por que é o `none`, é 1:1, basicamente \`\`\`X e `lang-X` dão no mesmo, basta seguir as [tabelas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7740/70) divulgadas aqui no meta.